# Output of C program including pointer variable

Tags: c, output

Given program -

```
main()
{
int i=10;
int *p;
p=&i;
printf("%d,%d",i,*p);
printf("%u,%u",&i,p);
printf("%d",p);
printf("%p,%p",&i,p);
printf("%u",&p);
*p=50;
printf("%d,%d",i,*p);
}
```

Let address of p is 265.

Then I know output of first printf statement is 10. And of second printf is 265. But after that I don't know. Please help me.

**Edit -**

This program from c language notes. Main problem is I don't have computer or laptop to run this program. So I am looking help here.

Comment: Using %u for formatting pointers is unreliable; use %p.  Ditto %d; it is for integers, not pointers.

Comment: What specifically is it you're having issues with? How far have you gotten?

Comment: I don't understand. What you mean?

Comment: I want to know output and explanation if possible.

Comment: @Amar - using anything other than `%p` to print out the value of a pointer results in *undefined behavior* - the lines that print `p` or `&p` with `%d` or `%u` will give you some kind of output, but it may not be the proper value for the pointer.  So the second, third, and fifth `printf` calls may not print out the actual pointer value.

Comment: use %p to print the value of a pointer (&i, p).

Comment: This is not a C program. The implicit int rule was removed from tbe language years ago. It is also illegal to call a standard library function before `#include`ing an appropriate library header.

Comment: 'But after that I don't know' what do you mean, you don't know?  What did you get when you ran it?  You did run it, surely?  I mean, you didn't just type it in from your printed homework?

Comment: @ThingyWotsit Sorry I don't have computer or laptop to run. This is the main problem and reason to ask here.

Comment: What?  We are not here to build/run/test code for you!

Comment: @amar try an online ide/compiler. google for it.

Answer (score 0):

First change a bit and add `\n` to formats:

```
    int i = 10;
    int *p;
    p = &i;
    printf ("%d,%d\n", i, *p);
    printf ("%u,%u\n", &i, p);
```

- declare `i` as integer that holds 10 as value
- declare `p` as integer pointer that can points to the address of 
  an integer variable in Memory.
- assign the address of `i` to `p` that lead to `p` points to `i`.
- print `i` value : 10 and contents of Memory location that `p` points on it (`i`)
- print address of `i` and address of `p`.
  (Note that as `p` is a pointer variable, using `p` is equal in meaning to `&i`)

**Code Output**

```
10,10
3219586576,3219586576
```